# Error while trying to convert a html to jsp

Tags: html, jsp

While converting html to jsp, I encountered an error called unterminated tag as in " 292:392: Unterminated tag". Does 292:392 point the line number ? If so which line number between 292 and 392 should I refer to for resolving the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

It refers to the `line-number:character-number`.

In your case it should be in the three hundred and ninety second character of the two hundred and ninety second line.

Answer (score 1):

292 refers to the line number and 392 refers to the character position in that line.